# Navigation using side menu not working in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a side navigation menu to add some navigation that I can't fit on the bottom navigation bar.

My problem is that I don't know how to make the menu items navigate to the assigned screens.

Here is the main screen where all the other screens are displayed in the container so I have the bottom navigation and appbar displayed on all screens. This screen is also where I add the side menu in the drawer.

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({super.key});

  // Added this for BottomNavigationBar sync
  // This allows the children to get the state of this page
  static MainScreenState? of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.findAncestorStateOfType<MainScreenState>();
  }

  @override
  //MainScreenState
  createState() => MainScreenState();
}

class MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  int _pageIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> appScreens = [
    const CompanyDashboardScreen(),
    const TransactionDetailScreen(true),
    const AppointmentCalendarScreen(),
    const UserProfileScreen(),
    const ChatScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: const SideMenu(),
      appBar: CustomAppBar(),
      body: Container(child: appScreens[_pageIndex]),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black45,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: _pageIndex,
        onTap: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _pageIndex = value;
          });
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Home"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add_business_outlined), label: "Trxn"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), label: "Calendar"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.people), label: "User"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.chat), label: 'Chat'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // Added this for BottomNavigationBar sync
  void setIndex(int index) {
    if (mounted) setState(() => _pageIndex = index);
  }
}
```

Here is the side menu code:

```
class SideMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  const SideMenu({super.key});

  @override
  State<SideMenu> createState() => _SideMenuState();
}

class _SideMenuState extends State<SideMenu> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance; // Need this to logout

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await auth.signOut();
  }

  final List<Widget> appScreens = [
    const CompanyDashboardScreen(),
    const TransactionDetailScreen(true),
    const AppointmentCalendarScreen(),
    const CompanyScreen(),
    const UserProfileScreen(),
    const ChatScreen(),
  ];

  void onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: (ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          const UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: Text('Billy Bob Baker'),
            accountEmail: Text('billy.bob.baker@gmail.com'),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Add Company'),
            selected: selectedIndex == 3,
            onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app
              onItemTapped(3);
              // Then close the drawer
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Add User'),
            selected: selectedIndex == 4,
            onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app
              onItemTapped(4);
              // Then close the drawer
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Log Out'),
            selected: selectedIndex == 6,
            onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app
              signOut();
              // Then close the drawer
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()));
            },
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

How do I make it navigate to another screen when I tap on the menu item? Should I use Navigator.push like I do in the logout menu item?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same logic of bottomNavigationBar.
Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const appTitle = 'Drawer Demo';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions[_selectedIndex],
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            const DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Home'),
              selected: _selectedIndex == 0,
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                _onItemTapped(0);
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Business'),
              selected: _selectedIndex == 1,
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                _onItemTapped(1);
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('School'),
              selected: _selectedIndex == 2,
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                _onItemTapped(2);
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I still don't see how I navigate to another screen. Look at my code, which I got from the same website you got this code from.

Comment: Because you don't use the same appScreens List. You should use the same List in BottomNavigationBar and SideMenu